# Simulating Dial-pad presses in Android

Tags: android

Is there a way to simulating the pressing of the dialpad keys in Android? I'm trying to create buttons on an Android app that correspond to different numbers, like if you call an automated service and you have to press "1" for English and "2" for Spanish, I'd like to make a button that says "English" such that you can press it and it'll input "1".

In my Activity, I've managed to create a service that overlays ontop the native Android call screen by calling a service then the number:

```
    String number = "222-222-2222";
    String uri = "tel:" + number.trim() ;
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
    startService(new Intent(this, Service.class));
    startActivity(intent);
```

I want to add to my Service buttons that will simulate the different dial number keys of Android. Is this possible? Or is my approach with the Service wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can do it on the fly. If you know the number sequence in advance and the delay in between, you can try with PhoneNumberUtils.WAIT technique.Similar thread below

[Making a Phone Call with a Number Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18216563/making-a-phone-call-with-a-number-extension)